# Routing (htaccess) subfolder to file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm working on an add-on (for a CMS) to include news. To prevent creating many index-files I tried to use redirection with htaccess, but it seems to be complex for me ;-)

I'm using a .htaccess for the CMS in the root directory:

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.php

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect from http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

# If called directly - redirect to short url version
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/page/intro.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /page
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Send the request to the index.php for processing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(page|backend|framework|include|languages|media|account|search|temp|templates/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\/\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]+)$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

# allow robots.txt (all other txt are denied before)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/robots\.txt$ [nocase]
RewriteRule \.txt$  -  [forbidden,last]
```

The current structure:

```
--> page/
----> folder1/accessfile.php
----> folder1/.htaccess
```

I'd like to redirect from:

```
 /page/folder1/accessfile/lorem/ipsum
```

and 
    /page/folder1/accessfile/lorem/ipsum/ #(folders that doesn't exist)

to:

```
/page/folder1/accessfile.php
```

I'd tried using this in `page/folder1/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^accessfile/.*$ ./accessfile.php
```

But this doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the htaccess file in your root directory alongside the `page/` directory. If your htaccess file already resides there, put the rewrite rules **before** the `# If called directly - redirect to short url version` line.

Here's what you need:

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # Make sure it's not an actula file/dir being accessed
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Make sure request uri does not contain the actual file 
    # name, avoiding recursive rewrite loops
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !accessfile\.php
    RewriteRule page/folder1/accessfile/?(.*)? /page/folder1/accessfile.php?q=$1 [R,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
## Results
# page/folder1/accessfile             => page/folder1/accessfile.php?q=
# page/folder1/accessfile/foo         => page/folder1/accessfile.php?q=foo
# page/folder1/accessfile/foo/bar     => page/folder1/accessfile.php?q=foo/bar
# page/folder1/accessfile/foo/bar/baz => page/folder1/accessfile.php?q=foo/bar/baz
```

As you see, for convenience, the rewrite rule rewrites the request URI as query string parameters. So the PHP file has access to the passed data using `$_GET['q']`.

If you wish to preserve the clean URL, and rewrite the request to the php file under the hood, drop that `R` flag.

Comment: That works nearly perfectly except one problem: Trailing slash... I made a little change to get /page/-redirection working  `    # Make sure request uri does not contain the actual file 
    # name, avoiding recursive rewrite loops
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !kurse\.php
    RewriteRule folder1/accessfile/?(.*)? /folder1/accessfile.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule page/folder1/accessfile/?(.*)? /page/schule-bildung/accessfile.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]` calling **page/folder1/accessfile** works fine but **page/folder1/accessfile/** doesn't redirect correctly.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. Both `page/folder1/accessfile` and `page/folder1/accessfile/` (with trailing slash) get redirected to `page/folder1/accessfile.php?q=` which is expected behavior.